# How to run a batch file before process starts?

Tags: c#, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to start a program with the following code:

```
private static void RunPlmxml(string plmxmlPath, string arguments) 
{
    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
    process.StartInfo.FileName = plmxmlPath;
    process.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["TC_ROOT"] = teamcenterRootPath;
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();

    // Other code

    return;
}
```

This works fine but, i am missing a lot of environment variables. These variables are set in `%TC_DATA%\tc_profilevars.bat`. I want to run this bat file before i start this process so that the program has all the variables it needs. So what i want to do is something like this:

```
private static void RunPlmxml(string plmxmlPath, string arguments) 
{
    string teamcenterRootPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TC_ROOT");
    string teamcenterDataPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TC_DATA");


    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
    process.StartInfo.FileName = plmxmlPath;
    process.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["TC_ROOT"] = teamcenterRootPath;
    process.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["TC_DATA"] = teamcenterDataPath;
    process.StartInfo.BeforeStart("%TC_DATA%\tc_profilevars.bat")

    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();

    // Other code

    return;
}
```

I do not want to create another bat file that starts this process since i do not want to ship my product with a bat file included.

Comment: You can try this: `Process.Start(teamcenterDataPath + "\\tc_profilevars.bat")`. You can hide console for this process if you want and also make use of Path.Combine if you do not want to concatenate string.

Comment: You don't need to ship a batch file. You can create one on the fly in the temp folder and then run that created cmd file and remove it once the process has exited.

Comment: `Process.Start("cmd /c \"%TC_DATA%\tc_profilevars.bat\" && somethingelse.exe");`